# Parsing and removing a matched string up to and including 3 escaped characters

Tags: python, ruby, bash, awk, sed

I have a file that is a 10000 line perl variable. This variable defines apps and their given dependencies. here is what that file looks like:

```
'im-an-app' =>
{    
    do-this =>
    {    
        needs => [ 'ruby', 'jboss', 'jquery' ],
        process =>
        [    
            { say => 'hi' },
            { speak => 'loudly' },
            { read => 'qucikly' },
        ],
    },
},

'im-an-app2' =>
{
    do-this =>
    {
        needs => [ 'ruby' ], # there is a comment here
    },
},

'im-an-app3' =>
{
    needs =>
    {
        requires => [ 'ruby', 'jboss', 'jquery', 'sass' ],
        process =>
        [
            { say => 'hi' },
            { speak => 'loudly' },
            { read => 'quickly' },
        ],
    },
},
```

I have a list of the apps i'd like to remove from the file in a seperate list.txt file that looks like:

```
im-an-app1
im-an-app3
im-an-app16
im-an-app17
im-an-app29
```

These apps are all different names and i'm using placeholders, I have about 500 i need to iterate over, match, and remove from my app file.

I've loaded the file IRB and when i read the file I get output in a format like this:

instances\n\t##\n\n\t'im-an-app' =>\n\t{\n\t\tdo-this =>\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tneeds       => [ 'ham-and-cheese-sandwich' ],\n\t\t},\n\t},\n\n\t'im-the-next-app' =>\n\t{\n\t\tneeds =>\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t# im a comment about this app\n\t\t\t# im another comment\n\t\t\tneeds => [ 'backlava', 'cand-corns', 'popscicles', 'yum-yum-bars', 'the-bomb-sauce', 'corndogs' ],\n\t\t\tdo-this =>\n\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t{ say => 'hi' },\n\t\t\t\t{ say => 'bye' },\n\t\t\t\t{ yell => 'i-love-gold' },\n\t\t\t],\n\t\t},\n\t},\n\n\t'im-the-third-app' =>\n\t{\n\t\tdothis =>\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tneeds => [ 'junk', 'jazz', 'json', 'jiffylube ],\n\t\t\tprocess =>\n\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t{ say => 'hi' },\n\t\t\t\t{ say => 'bye' },\n\t\t\t\t{ say => 'goonies' },\n\t\t\t],\n\t\t},\n\t},\n\n\t'im-yet-anotherapp'

I have noticed that the only constant delimiter is a \n\n\t that exists only before the definition of the new app. I'd like to search through the read file, delete the reference to each application in my list and all of its subsequent information up to and including the \n\n\t.

I'm using Ruby and IRB to do this but I'm open to using other forms of manipulation.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic for SO. You'll get a much better response to your question if you make an attempt at coding the solution yourself and paste your code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted python, this may be a start (untested so may have bugs):

```
import re
with open( 'yourfilename', 'r' ) as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n\n\t')
    # then you can use some regex to find what you want.
    for entry in data:
        reres = re.search( 'yourpattern', entry )
        if reres:
            del entry
    # Save the results to another file?
    with open( 'outputfile', 'wt' ) as fout:
        fout.write( "\n\n\t".join( data ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

(**EDIT**: Updated based on new sample data)

This awk, demonstrated below, loads the list of apps into an array (adding surrounding single quotes so as to match the app file). Then for the app file it changes the record separator to be one or more blank lines (`RS=""`). For each record it prints only the ones that weren't in the list:

```
$ awk -v ORS="\n\n" -v q="'" 'NR==FNR{a[q $1 q];next} !($1 in a)' app-list.txt RS="" apps.txt
```

**Explanation**

```
-v ORS="\n\n"
```

Set the Output Record Separator to keep an extra newline between app
records when writing them out.

```
-v q="'"
```

This is just convenient way to be able to use a literal single quote in the
one-liner, which since itself is surrounded by single quotes can otherwise be a pain.

```
NR==FNR{a[q $1 q];next}
```

When `NR==FNR` we are reading the first file, the list of apps (go to http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ and serach for "Two-file Processing"). For each app in the list, surround it with single quotes and enter it into the array `a`.

```
!($1 in a)
```

Once we get here we know we are reading the apps file (again, see above
link). In this file each app block is considered a single record (see
`RS=""`, below).  `$1` is the name of the app in quotes. We check to see if
the name is in the array `a` and if *not*, we perform the default action, which
is to simply print the record.

```
app-list.txt RS="" apps.txt
```

These are the files to be processed. Awk allows you to change `RS`, the
record separator between files. For the app list, the defaults are fine,
but for the apps themselves we set the record separator to the empty
string. As the docs say, "*By a special dispensation, an empty string as
the value of RS indicates that records are separated by one or more blank
lines*", which is quite convenient for this application.

**Demonstration**:

```
$ cat app-list.txt
im-an-app1
im-an-app3
im-an-app16
im-an-app17
im-an-app29


$ cat apps.txt
'im-an-app1' =>
{
    do-this =>
    {
        needs => [ 'ruby', 'jboss', 'jquery' ],
        process =>
        [
            { say => 'hi' },
            { speak => 'loudly' },
            { read => 'qucikly' },
        ],
    },
},

'im-an-app2' =>
{
    do-this =>
    {
        needs => [ 'ruby' ], # there is a comment here
    },
},

'im-an-app3' =>
{
    needs =>
    {
        requires => [ 'ruby', 'jboss', 'jquery', 'sass' ],
        process =>
        [
            { say => 'hi' },
            { speak => 'loudly' },
            { read => 'quickly' },
        ],
    },
},


$ awk -v ORS="\n\n" -v q="'" 'NR==FNR{a[q $1 q];next} !($1 in a)' app-list.txt RS="" apps.txt

'im-an-app2' =>
{
    do-this =>
    {
        needs => [ 'ruby' ], # there is a comment here
    },
},
```

Comment: This is the exact behavior I'm looking for, but i've tried the awk command and it just prints out my apps file. Your second awk command looks to be the same as the first one listed.

Comment: Yes, the second is the same as the first. It was only to show the command "in action".  If you edit your question to include sample data from both the apps file and the list-of-apps file, with four or five complete apps, I'm sure we can work it out. Note that my list-of-apps file includes the single-quotes around the app names. Does yours?

Comment: Wow! I think that solved it!! awk is super fast also! Can you break this down this command for me so I can leverage this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in Python as follows:

```
import re

remove = set(['im-an-ap', 'im-an-ap-5', 'im-an-ap-10'])

def replace(re_app):
    if re_app.group(2) in remove:
        return ""
    else:
        return re_app.group(1)

with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(re.sub(r"(^'(.*?)' =.*?(?=\n\n\t|\Z))", replace, f_input.read(), flags=re.S+re.M))
```

This will load the file `input.txt`, remove all of the unwanted entries and create a new file called `output.txt`.